# How to fix unity's text alpha blinking script to stop blinking when mouse button was clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script makes unity text alpha channel go from 0.1 to 1. 
I want to make this text go smoothly to 0 when mouse button was clicked.

I tried fixing it.

```
 public float minAlpha = 0.1f; // The minimum value of the alpha channel, from 0.
    public float maxAlpha = 0.9f; // The maximum value of the alpha channel, up to 1.
    public float timerAlpha = 0.0f; // The conditional time for changing the magnitude of the alpha channel value.

    private float minAlphaZ;
    private float maxAlphaZ;
    private float timerAlphaZ;
    private float alphazxc;
    private bool timertr = false;
    private Color rezcolor;

    void Start()
    {
        alphazxc = minAlpha;
        minAlphaZ = minAlpha;
        maxAlphaZ = maxAlpha;
        timerAlphaZ = timerAlpha / 100.0f; // The conditional time.
        rezcolor = this.GetComponent<Text>().color; // The current value of the color of the text.
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (timertr == false) // Increase the minimum value of the alpha channel, to the maximum.
        {
            minAlphaZ += timerAlphaZ * Time.deltaTime;
            alphazxc = minAlphaZ;
            if (minAlphaZ >= maxAlpha)
            {
                timertr = true;
                minAlphaZ = minAlpha;
            }
        }

        if (timertr == true) // Decrease the maximum value of the alpha channel, to the minimum.
        {
            maxAlphaZ -= timerAlphaZ * Time.deltaTime;
            alphazxc = maxAlphaZ;
            if (maxAlphaZ <= minAlpha)
            {
                timertr = false;
                maxAlphaZ = maxAlpha;
            }
        }




        this.GetComponent<Text>().color = new Color(rezcolor.r, rezcolor.g, rezcolor.b, alphazxc);


    }
}
```

I expected that text alpha channel would smoothly go into 0 but it doesn't.

Comment: `timerAlphaZ = 0` There won't be changes (`minAlphaZ += timerAlphaZ * Time.deltaTime;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `FixedUpdate` is only used for the Physics. In all other cases you should use `Update` which is called frame wise instead of in certain fixed time intervals.

---

It is also very inefficient to re-call `GetComponent` all the time. rather store it once and reuse the reference later.

---

For what you are trying to do it is always better to use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which are easier to control and maintain.

Then another hint: Use the [`[Range(min,max)]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RangeAttribute.html) attribute for your Inspector to make clear no incorrect values can be entered.

```
// if possible reference this already via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Text text;

[Range(0f, 1f)] public float minAlpha = 0.1f; 

[Range(0f, 1f)] public float maxAlpha = 0.9f; 

[Tooltip("The fade duration in seconds")]
public float fadeOutDuration = 1.0f;

[Tooltip("blinking speed in blinks per second")]
public float blinkingSpeed = 1.0f;

// for controlling the end of blinking on click
private bool blink;

private void Start()
{
    if(!text) text = GetComponent<Text>();

    // start blinking
    StartCoroutine(BlinkingRoutine())
}

private IEnumerator BlinkingRoutine()
{
    // get the original color and setup min, max and fadeout color once
    originalColor = text.color;
    var maxColor = new Color(originalColor.r, originalColor.g, originalColor.b, maxAlpha);
    var minColor = new Color(originalColor.r, originalColor.g, originalColor.b, minAlpha);
    var fadeOutColor = new Color(originalColor.r, originalColor.g, originalColor.b, 0.0f);

    blink = true;

    var passedTime = 0f;
    while(blink)
    {
         // always loops forth and back between 0 and 1
         lerpFactor = Mathf.PingPong(passedTime, 1);
         // optionaly add ease-in and ease-out
         //lerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, lerpFactor);

         // change the order of minColor and maxColor
         // depending on the one you want to start with
         text.color = Color.Lerp(maxColor, minColor, lerpFactor);

         // add time passed since last frame multiplied by blinks/second
         passedTime += Time.deltaTime * blinkingSpeed;

         // allow this frame to be rendered and continue
         // from here in the next frame
         yield return null;
    }

    // set alpha to max
    text.color = new Color(originalColor.r, originalColor.g, originalColor.b, maxAlpha);

    // start fading out
    passedTime = 0f;
    while(passedTime < fadeOutDuration)
    {
        var lerpFactor = passedTime / fadeDuration;
        // optionally add ease-in and ease-out
        //lerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, lerpFactor);

        text.color = Color.Lerp(maxColor, fadeOutColor, lerpFactor);

        passedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    // just to be sure set it to 0 hard
    text.color = fadeOutColor;

    // optionally hide or destroy this gameObject when done
    //gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //Destroy(gameObject);
}

public void HandleClick()
{
    // if is blinking this stops blinking and fades out
    blink = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing these heavy stuff by your own. You can use [DoTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676).

Sample code for fading to 0 in 1 seconds

```
GetComponent<Text>().DoFade(0f,1.0f); // first is your target alpha value & second is the time.
```

Same way you can go from 0 to 1 also.